# How to edit the style of multiple Oracle Apex applications in a workspace

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to edit the style of multiple applications inside my workspace with the less amout of effort. What I mean by "edit the style" is font size, background color, position, etc.

My idea was creating a CSS file at "Static Workspace Files" with the classes I want and applying them to the apex items needed. Applying this in a region for instance:

```
*.font16{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

The problem is: modal pages can't find the file, which is not a problem in nomral pages. I'm using the path '#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#styles.css' in the page "CSS > File URLs" setting.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, maybe I should edit Themes or Templates, but since I'm pretty new to Apex I chose CSS for familiarity.

Application Express v20.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what Static Workspace Files are meant for, files that can be used by multiple applications in the same workspace.
The easiest approach for this is to create a CSS, like what you've done.
You don't need to inlcude the file in every single page, which would become a maintenance nightmare eventually.
You can simply include the file at the application level:
In Share Components, go in the User Interface Attributes and include the file under Cascading Style Sheets.
I usually have one global.css file (as a static workspace file) for anything common to all my apps and one app.css per application (as a static application file) for things specific to the current application.

[image: screenshot]

Note that application exports will contain the static application files, but they will not contain the static workspace files. You will need to export/import them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **Theme Roller**? Run the page, it is down in developer's toolbar.

[image]

Comment: No, I didn't. Can this be reapplied to multiple applications? What I'm trying to avoid is to enter every single application to edit their style.

Comment: It works for a single application, but - if that's a single CSS you have, you'd apply it once per application. How many applications do you have, anyway? (I'm not trying to suggest you to do it if you don't want to, I'm just curious).

Comment: At least 15 applications. Can the "Static Workspace Files" CSS file be imported this way? If so, can you tell me how?

Comment: 15 applications; that's nice. I don't know whether you can (or can not) import static workspace CSS here, sorry.